# How to get KML file Polygon Based on name using C#?

Tags: c#

How to get KML file coordinate values based on AK ?

I tried below code to get polygon values :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"E:\BSSProducts\BI\GEOMap\GEOMap\US States.xml");
List<XElement> placemarks = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Placemark")
    .ToList();

List<string> polygon1 = placemarks.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Polygon")
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

It's working fine. But I don't know how to pass name to get particular polygon coordinate values.

Example:

```
List<XElement> MultiGeometry = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "MultiGeometry") && (? == "AK"))
    .ToList();
```

How to solve this ?